# Where have our moderators gone?

Tags: discussion, moderation

As of 25th Jan 2015 at 18.55 GMT

- Andrei last seen 48 minutes ago
- Hrafn last seen Jan 5 at 17:08
- yuttadhammo last seen Dec 20 '14 at 15:09

2 out of 3 moderators are missing in action. I can kind of understand this - there might be some long retreats going on, family issues, anything really.

Is this a problem? Does it matter? Does Andrei mind being the only moderator?

Comment: Sorry, I've been away in Asia... back now :)

Answer (score 3):

We can help, by checking the review queue etc.

I personally miss them more for their answers (but I'm also grateful that they answered so many questions so well, in the past).

Maybe there's not too very much moderation to do, at the moment?
I haven't flagged anything in days.

If you do ever have some urgent need for a moderator, I suspect you can get one (get a moderator's attention in a hurry) by flagging a message in the chat room. SFAIK a flag on a chat message will be seen by (many) site-wide moderators instead of only by (the few) Buddhism-specific moderators.

Alternatively there's the [Help Center > Contact](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) page.

Comment: That's good advice thanks. I didn't know about the site wide chat flags. I guess the disappearance of high rep users is perhaps more the point but that will always occur with all sites. I have to say that the volume of questions is going up now so the absence of moderators might become more of an issue as we go on. See how we go

Comment: Even when the mods are quiet, Community Managers do regular sweeps of site metas to make sure nothing is on fire, so you can usually get ahold of one of us here, too.